# After a reinstall, how do I force Windows to reconnect User and ProgramData folders that have been moved to another drive?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, restore, reinstall, windows-backup

I moved a friend's User folder to drive D: using the 'mklink in recovery mode' method a while ago, which worked fine.  I then used Windows Backup to back everything up, and reinstalled Windows 7, moving both the User and ProgramData folders using [this method](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/124198-user-profiles-create-move-during-windows-7-installation.html), which works well.

The problem is that, even after restoring the backup (which *shouldn't* have been necessary, as nothing on D: was touched during the reinstallation), Windows still doesn't see the accounts.

I spent over two hours looking for the 'official' way to reconnect all of the accounts, but found nothing that I was positive was the best way to go about it.  What is the best way to do it?

Comment: is that you reinstalled the OS or recovery the OS from the backup. Replacing the folders in new OS wont take effect as it will required registry level entries for the User profiles

Comment: Reinstalled the OS, restored the folders from backup, though they weren't deleted by the install, as they had already been moved to another partition.